# onCreate handler's DocumentSnapshot undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to set a trigger for an onCreate event in a subcollection. I can get the event to trigger fine, but for some reason the DocumentSnapshot is undefined when I try to access it.

My function is based on the sample here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/child-count/functions/index.js

```
exports.onCreateReview = functions.firestore
.document('spots/{spotId}/reviews/{reviewId}')
.onCreate(
    (snapshot, _) => {
        console.log(snapshot.exists())
        const collectionRef = snapshot.ref.parent
        const countRef = collectionRef.parent.child('num_reviews');

        const promise = countRef.transaction((current) => {
            return current + 1;
        });

        console.log('num_reviews incremented');
        return promise;
    });
```

When I check the logs in my Firebase project, I get a TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Comment: upon doing a little more searching, I found this: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/399. Seems like there's a bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Which thing is undefined?  Track it down with a line number in the trace.

Comment: Also bear in mind that you're not handling promises correctly.  transaction() returns a promise that you need to return from the function to tell Cloud Functions when the async work is done.

Comment: sorry  for not specifying. It's the 'snapshot' variable that is undefined.

Comment: snapshot should never be undefined.  What does your package.json look like? What versions of the SDKs?  Make sure you're on the latest.

Comment: Ok, so after deleting all of the code in the callback function, I started with a fresh `console.log(snapshot.ref.path)` and things magically started to work (no more undefined) but I started to question some other stuff. `collectionRef.parent` is a DocumentReference, but looking at the documentation there doesn't seem to be a `.child()` method. Is there something I'm missing here

Comment: It sounds like now you have a different question than the one you started out with.  This normally calls for a new question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

A snapshot is not a promise as it can fire multiple times whereas a promise resolves once.

Here's a snippet of one of my `.onCreate` functions that you might find helpful as a guide.

```
exports.newFeedback = functions.firestore.document("feedback/{feedback}").onCreate(function (snap, context) {
    var feedbackObj = snap.data();
    var msg = feedbackObj.message;
    var subject = "New Feedback: " + msg.substring(0,36);
    var feedbackMsg = {
        to: "ron@hightechtele.com",
        from: "noreply@hightechtele.com",
        subject: subject,
        templateId: "----------------------------",
        substitutionWrappers: ["{{", "}}"],
        substitutions: {
            message: msg,
            senderDisplayName: feedbackObj.sender,
            senderEmail: feedbackObj.senderEmail,
            senderUid: feedbackObj.senderUid
        }
    };
    return sendgrid.send(feedbackMsg);
});
```